# String concatenation from a list of string, using a praticle in front and one at the end for each element

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have an array of strings:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to obtain:

```
s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d
```

I tried:

```
"s., ".join(fields)
```

Doesn't work because I need `s.` in front and `,` at the end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were very close. Use a list comprehension for the operation you want to perform on every string, and then join the list of strings together:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
', '.join(['s.'+x for x in data])
# 's.a, s.b, s.c, s.d'
```

Answer (score 8):

You should perform a *mapping* of the individual elements from `'x'` to `'s.x'`, we can do that by:

```
map('s.{}'.format, data)
```

then we can join these together by a comma:

```
', '.join(map('s.{}'.format, data))
```

this yields:

```
>>> ', '.join(map('s.{}'.format, data))
's.a, s.b, s.c, s.d'
```

Or like [@JonClements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140209/string-concatenation-from-a-list-of-string-using-a-praticle-in-front-and-one-at/53140247?noredirect=1#comment93172548_53140247) says, since [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6), we can use [literal string interpolation [PEP-498]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
', '.join(f's.{d}' for d in data)
```